Dotnet GraphQL - Not producing logs on InternalServerErrors
When our GraphQL server responds with a InternalServerError, no logs are being produced; leading to unknown bugs.
I've added some middleware to handle the expection but nothing appears to be logging, and only half works.
Program.cs - Adding Middleware
app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionLoggerMiddleware>();
ExceptionLoggerMiddleware.cs - Exception Handler
using Serilog;

namespace Example.common;

public class ExceptionLoggerMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public ExceptionLoggerMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(ex, "An unhandled exception occured");
            throw;
        }
    }
}

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appriecated !
